# Can you shadow copy MAF Addins in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, shadow-copy, maf

Is it possible to configure MAF in an ASP.NET such a way that it loads shadow copies of an addin assembly?  I'd like the ability to update an addin without manually restarting the web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be possible.